# Photo Size With UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: iphone

I have one problem to print photo using AirPrint. I printed 4 * 6 inch image but printed image size is too large! How can I resolve this problem.
Can I specify paper size and photo programmatically?

Here is screen shot url.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f6wa0waao56zqk/IMG_0532.jpg

` here is my code

```
-(void)printPhotoWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{ 
    NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.f);
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:myData]) {

        pic.delegate = self;
        UIPrintInfo *pinfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        pinfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
        pinfo.jobName = @"My Photo";
        pinfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

        pic.printInfo = pinfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = myData;

        pic.printFormatter = format;
        [format release];

        void(^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

            [self resignFirstResponder];

            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"--- print error! ---");
            }
        };

        [pic presentFromRect:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 64) + 27, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 16) + 55, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}

- (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList
{
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(6 * 72, 4 * 72);
    return [UIPrintPaper bestPaperForPageSize:pageSize withPapersFromArray:paperList];
}
```

Just this is my code. should I use `UIPrintPageRenderer` property to give draw area?

`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but I'm new to this site and so I can't attach my code unfortunately.

I have specified paper size and also what should I do to limit photo size?

Comment: update the question use the hight and width of images you want not inches  :(

Comment: @user2374360 - to post your code you can use the 'code snippet' tool when editing your question. It's the icon that looks like two curly braces (**{ }**).

Comment: thanks for your tell me. so I can show my code using {}.:)

Comment: hi lxt,

Can I upload the photo using other tool?

Comment: I have attached screenshot! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

first you should set

```
 /*
 PrintPhotoPageRenderer *pageRenderer = [[PrintPhotoPageRenderer alloc]init];
    pageRenderer.imageToPrint =image;
    pic.printPageRenderer = pageRenderer;
*/
 - (void)printImage {
// Obtain the shared UIPrintInteractionController
UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController     sharedPrintController];
controller.delegate = self;
if(!controller){
    NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
    return;
}

// We need a completion handler block for printing.
UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController     *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if(completed && error)
        NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain,     error.code);
};

// Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
UIImage *image = ((UIImageView *)self.view).image;
[controller setDelegate:self];


printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;

if(!controller.printingItem && image.size.width > image.size.height)
    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;

// Use this printInfo for this print job.
controller.printInfo = printInfo;

//  Since the code below relies on printingItem being zero if it hasn't
//  already been set, this code sets it to nil.
controller.printingItem = nil;


#if DIRECT_SUBMISSION
// Use the URL of the image asset.
if(self.imageURL && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:self.imageURL])
    controller.printingItem = self.imageURL;
#endif

// If we aren't doing direct submission of the image or for some reason we don't
// have an ALAsset or URL for our image, we'll draw it instead.
if(!controller.printingItem){
    // Create an instance of our PrintPhotoPageRenderer class for use as the
    // printPageRenderer for the print job.
    PrintPhotoPageRenderer *pageRenderer = [[PrintPhotoPageRenderer alloc]init];
    // The PrintPhotoPageRenderer subclass needs the image to draw. If we were taking
    // this path we use the original image and not the fullScreenImage we obtained from
    // the ALAssetRepresentation.
    //pageRenderer.imageToPrint = ((UIImageView *)self.view).image;
    pageRenderer.imageToPrint =image;
    controller.printPageRenderer = pageRenderer;
}

// The method we use presenting the printing UI depends on the type of
// UI idiom that is currently executing. Once we invoke one of these methods
// to present the printing UI, our application's direct involvement in printing
// is complete. Our delegate methods (if any) and page renderer methods (if any)
// are invoked by UIKit.
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //[controller presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES     completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPad
     [controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) inView:_btnPrint animated:YES     completionHandler:completionHandler];
}else
    [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPhone

}
```

and then you should set PrintPhotoPageRenderer

UIPrintPageRenderer.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface PrintPhotoPageRenderer : UIPrintPageRenderer {   UIImage
*imageToPrint; }

@property (readwrite, retain) UIImage *imageToPrint;

@end

//
```

PrintPhotoPageRenderer.m

```
 #import "PrintPhotoPageRenderer.h"

@implementation PrintPhotoPageRenderer

@synthesize imageToPrint;

// This code always draws one image at print time.
-(NSInteger)numberOfPages {   return 1; }

/*  When using this UIPrintPageRenderer subclass to draw a photo at
print
    time, the app explicitly draws all the content and need only override
    the drawPageAtIndex:inRect: to accomplish that.

    The following scaling algorithm is implemented here:
    1) On borderless paper, users expect to see their content scaled so that there is             no whitespace at the edge of the paper. So this
code scales the content to  fill the paper at the expense of
clipping any content that lies off the paper.
    2) On paper which is not borderless, this code scales the content so that it fills    the paper. This reduces the size of the
photo but does not clip any content.
*/
- (void)drawPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex inRect:(CGRect)printableRect {

      if(self.imageToPrint){

      CGSize finialSize =  CGSizeMake(560, 431);//you should set width and height for you self

      int x  =  20;

      int y = (printableRect.size.height - finialSize.height);

      CGRect finalRect = CGRectMake(x, y, finialSize.width, finialSize.height);

    [self.imageToPrint drawInRect:finalRect];

         }else {
    NSLog(@"%s No image to draw!", __func__);   } }

@end
```